# What should I do about metal strip sticking out from under car?

Tags: underbody

There is a thin strip of metal sticking out of the bottom of my car (2018 Camry). I'm not sure if it's part of the car that has come out of place, or something from the road that got stuck in the car. Should I pull it out, if possible? Or take the car to the shop? Here's a picture:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I've edited the image into your question for you.

Comment: Tin can+wire coat hanger+duct tape...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The metal strip does not look like it's part of the vehicle. My suggestion is to pull it out. When you do, use some kind of silicone caulking or even black Permatex sealant to plug the hole. You don't need moisture getting into the vehicle from the underbody.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be attached to a plastic undertray, and looks like it's a parts label of some sort. If you're near the dealer, you can have them take it off (it'll be covered under the warranty), or you should just be able to strip it off yourself.